# WSO2 Gateway - 404 when accessing pages on port 8243/8280 but 9443 working, so all APIs running into 404 breaking our whole system

Tags: wso2, aws-api-gateway, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

OK we've lost 2 days of sleep trying to fix this, ugh.

Context: I never dealt with WSO2 before. AWS, WSO2 API-Manager, Gateway-Worker, 3 year old instance, we decided to Encrypt the volume, but since it was Autoscaled, we decided to do the encryption on the AMI Level and associate it with a Launch Configuration.

2 days ago, we decided to finally go with the encryption, feeling confident with our image and snapshots as backups. So we terminated the instance, Autoscaling fired another one up, and we SSH'd into it to start the wso2server.sh service.

And now all of the API calls to it are running into a 404 for whatever reason. Confirmed that 9443 is working since we can access :9443/publisher and :9443/store, but :8243/api and :8280/api are all just "Resource not available" (error 404).

The frontend application is highly dependent on these API Calls, so everything is broken right now.

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas. I'm hoping we don't need to change anything regarding the Key Manager and Publisher-Store instances, since we don't want to break even more things.

As a reference, we did change configuration XMLs according to this tutorial here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager . We're really kind of lost why we're encountering this 404.

HUGE thank you in advance to anyone who could point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh geez, this is one of those "I feel so dumb" moments. Turns out that the image that the Autoscaling was using was using data from back in 2015, meaning all activity for 3 years was missing. So all I did was get the old snapshot's data and copy it into the new instance manually.

Will definitely optimize the launch configuration to use a more updated gateway as a result of this revelation.